# How would a native english speak say "if you look at someone's point of view"?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Consider the hypothetical scenario,

> John thinks he is trying to help his friends. But, if **thinks from Jane's point of view**, he is insulting all of this friends.

Is there a  verb just would convey the same meaning as "thinking from one's point of view"? "Thinking from one's point of view" feels very verbose.

Answer (score 2):

All of these would be acceptable. I would not worry about verbosity.

- John thought he was trying to help his friends. But when he thought about it from Jane's point of view, he realized he was insulting all of his friends.
- John thought he was trying to help his friends. But considering Jane's point of view, he realized he was insulting all of his friends.
- John thought he was trying to help his friends. But when he thought about it from Jane's perspective, he realized he was insulting all of his friends.
- John thought he was trying to help his friends. But considering Jane's perspective, he realized he was insulting all of his friends.

Comment: Or simply _but, from Jane's point of view..._